# jquery - send string to php to safe it in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i got this script, which i found in the web:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('a.closeEl').bind('click', toggleContent);
        $('div.groupWrapper').Sortable(
            {
                accept: 'groupItem',
                helperclass: 'sortHelper',
                activeclass :   'sortableactive',
                hoverclass :    'sortablehover',
                handle: 'div.itemHeader',
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                onChange : function(ser)
                {
                },
                onStart : function()
                {
                    $.iAutoscroller.start(this, document.getElementsByTagName('body'));
                },
                onStop : function()
                {
                    $.iAutoscroller.stop();


                }
            }
        );
    }
);
var toggleContent = function(e)
{
    var targetContent = $('div.itemContent', this.parentNode.parentNode);
    if (targetContent.css('display') == 'none') {
        targetContent.slideDown(300);
        $(this).html('[-]');
    } else {
        targetContent.slideUp(300);
        $(this).html('[+]');
    }
    return false;
};
function serialize(s)
{
    serial = $.SortSerialize(s);
    alert(serial.hash);

};
</script>
<div  class="serializer">
<a href="#" onClick="serialize(); return false;" >serialize all lists</a>


</div>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">var client_id = 1;</script>
```

at the bottom of the script is the "function serialize", which is called by clicking on the link below. Can someone tell me, how can i send the variable "serial.hash" to a php-file to save it in mysql-database?

many thanks, maschek

Comment: Don't rollback the edits please. It was only edited to improve the formatting so the script was on multiple lines and highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) to send request to a PHP script which submits the data to a database. The JQuery documents contain a lot of examples. If you use a HTTP GET request, be warned there is a limit on the amount of data you can pass. This is browser dependant. I would recommend using [jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) as the method of sending data.

All the PHP script has to do is read the variables either from $_GET or $_POST (whichever method you use), sanitize them and submit them to the database.

Comment: thank you guys for the quick replies. so could i just place jQuery.post into the following?

function serialize(s)
{
    serial = $.SortSerialize(s);
    alert(serial.hash);

};

The var which i wanna send is already in there, now i would prefer the $_POST method to send it. So would it just be enough place the code from the Link, Yacoby have sent into the "function serialize"
and read it out in an php-file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Yacoby says $.post() or jQuery.post

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems very simple now:

```
$.post("test.php",{'func':'serial'},function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```